# pathfinding for agents bigger than 1x1 tile

Tags: path-finding

I'm creating a game with grid based movement, only, the units that move can be larger than 1x1 square tile. Any advice on how to make pathfinding work in that case?

My current thought is to assign a "desirability" variable to each tile. The desirability of the tile represents how much a given unit wants to occupy that tile. (for enemies that rush down the player, the closer a tile is to the player to more desirable it is, for an enemy that wants to flee, the opposite is true, for enemies that attack with ranged orthogonal projectiles, the tiles in orthogonal paths of the player is desirable etc.)

When a unit wants to move, it creates a list of "possible positions" which represent positions that it can move into on the next step. Then, the unit sums up the desirability of all tiles each possible position would be occupying (the desirability of 4 tiles will be summed for a 2x2 tile unit). Then, it simply chooses to move into the most desirable position.

For situations where a unit needs to navigate a maze, the desirability of the tiles will be calculated based on the walkable distance of each tile from the goal.

Is there any obvious oversight/performance issue that you can see here?

Answer (score 0):

The only special thing that needs to be done is to ignore tiles that a 2x2 character can't stand in. This can be done at the pathfinding-algorithm level, or by generating a new graph that has the ignored tiles removed.